# Effective bandwidth of mismatched PCIe card and slot

Tags: bandwidth, pci-express

What happened if :

1. x16 PCIe 2.0 card into x16 PCIe 3.0 slot (but electrically x8 link due to sharing)
2. x16 PCIe 3.0 card into x16 PCIe 2.0 slot (but electrically x8 link due to sharing)
3. x8 PCIe 3.0 card into x16 PCIe 2.0 slot

Comment: Are you asking about each as a separate case, or what the net result would be if you did all three at the same time?

Comment: @fixer1234 separate case

Answer (score 0):

After read the Specs, I conclude the least denominator rule apply here. Therefor for all three cases : 8 lanes PCIe 2.0 mode used = 4GB/s